# 100k HTTP Requests simultaneously

Tags: performance, rest, load-testing

I have to test my rest API such that 100k API calls are made simultaneously(within 500ms).Any Idea how to simulate it?Utility to use?

Comment: there are a few cloud based products

Comment: This size and timeframe is suspect for a human user population.  Humans are chaotic instruments and such coordination typically requires a clock tick and an automated agent.  Consider validating with your web/web service request logs the arrival model as a cross check.  If the information being sent is identical then architecturally you might consider a push model paired with a CDN for all 100K users to receive the information nearly instantaneously without taking the request load on your host.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use JMeter too, it enable your test to create multiple concurrent jmeter server. Just to be clear you can control multiple remote JMeter engines from a single JMeter client and replicate a test across many computers and thus simulate a larger load on the target server.

To be honest, your target is quite high (100k API calls simultaneously within 500ms), i.e. you'll need a lot of jmeter servers. When you create stress tests, there are not magical recipes, guides or manuals. Trial and error is a fundamental method of solving this kind of problems.

In my experience, I first try with few concurrent users and see how the server react. Then increase the number of concurrent users till to reach an intolerable performance decrease or, worst, a bottleneck .

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will obviously need a load testing tool which can be run in a distributed mode, i.e. 1 controller and X load generators executing the same test.

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) - scripts are written in some Python dialect
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - this guy doesn't require any specific knowledge, you can create tests using simple GUI
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) - is written in [Erlang](https://www.erlang.org/), known for capability to produce high loads even on low-end hardware.

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for more information on above tools.

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a 100% pure
>   Java application designed to load test functional behavior and measure
>   performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications
>   but has since expanded to other test functions.